# Is there an equivalent in JSON of PHP's explode() function?

Tags: json, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I'm trying, in SharePoint Online, to make a column formatting that gets the file name but without the extension.

I've written a code that uses $FileLeafRef to get that, but it also returns the extension (ex.: document.docx)

{

"$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",

"elmType": "div",

"txtContent": "[$FileLeafRef]"

}

I'd like to know if there is a possibility, like in PHP, to return only what is before the "."

Thanks

Comment: PHP is a language. JSON is a file format. Apples and origins.

Comment: Yes I know. And that's why I ask if there is a way despite this

Comment: You may want to rephrase your question though. JSON can't return anything. It is not executable, it is text. It's like politely asking a hamburger to teach you how to make vinaigrette. Hamburger is as likely to give you a response as JSON is. I am not familiar with Sharepoint Online; if your code is in JavaScript, ask about JavaScript, if it's .NET, ask about .NET etc. You need a programming language to do this.

Comment: Ok thank you for your help. As I'm not an English speaker, it's not easy for me to use appropriate terms. SharePoint does not use Javascript, I have to make it only with JSON... Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

There is no OOB function to get file name only.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting

Workaround:

Create a workflow to update (title/or custom filed) value when file uploaded.

[image]